# How to navigate the URL after booking page

Tags: 7, views, nodes, commerce, hooks

I have node content type for booking and created booking page in drupal 7 and same page is displaying error, confirmation and booking page. I am trying to split into three different pages(nodes) using same `node--booking.tpl.php` content type. I have custom `booking.class.php` that manages the booking process using two steps function `prebooking` and `postbooking`

After booking, I would like to redirect to `xyz.com/booking-confirm` if it's successfully booking and if it's error `xyz.com/booking-error` and currently, using `xyz.com/booking` for all actions.

What should I do? I am not sure, which option works. I have found this using some articles and stuck at this point.

1. Should I use header to redirect it?

   ```
   header('Location: /booking-confirm'); 
   header('Location: /booking-error');
   ```
2. Should I hook them in `template.php`?

   `function MYMODULE_user_register_form($form, &$form_state) {
       $form_state['redirect'] = 'path/to/somewhere';
   }`
3. Should I use `drupal_goto` to redirect it? it's in `booking.class.php` class?
4. Should I use `hook_init`? It's in `template.php` or `booking.class.php` ?

I am not sure, which is correct option to figure it out. I would like to split the URL using same content type. Any approach to solve the issue.

Comment: "I am not sure, which option works" Well have you tried any of them? If not, why not?

Comment: I have few but does not helps me. I thought would have been ask to make sure..I am on right path. Do you have option?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use form state to do redirects since users are interacting with forms. `header` is not really want you want and neither is `drupal_goto`.

The class(es) should return either a success/fail style response to the caller (in form submit) and based on that, you should handle the response and redirect with form_state redirect. The only job of your booking class should be to create a booking, it does not need to handle redirects or worry about any of that logic.

Also, no, absolutely don't do redirects from `hook_init`.

Vanilla example:

```
function myform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $book = new MyBookingClass();
  $form_data = $form_state['values'];

  // createBooking() returns either TRUE or FALSE

  if ($book->createBooking($form_state['values'])) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = '/booking-confirm';
  } else {
    // There was some sort of error.
    $form_state['redirect'] = '/booking-error';
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! let me review this your answer on my end. Thank you Kevin.

Comment: Is this function goes in booking class or custom display module?

Comment: Wherever your form code is for the booking form? It does not go in the class.

Comment: The thing with this answer is though, @Kevin you're assuming he's used Form API and proper FAPI processes to do this, which OP doesn't mention anywhere in his question.

Comment: Oh, well, that will certainly make it a lot more harder than it needs to be.